# Tensorflow error for zero vector: dims must be a vector of int32

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to initialize zero vectors in tensorflow as follow:

```
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    # Tensorflow run
    sess =  tf.Session() 
    sess.run(init)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: dims must be a vector of int32.
```

Can you please help me fixing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I solved the issue by updating tensorflow. Thanks for reading anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if you do this

```
W = tf.zeros([784, 10])
b = tf.zeros([10])

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# Tensorflow run
sess =  tf.Session() 
sess.run(init)
```

Also if you do it the way you're doing it. You'd still need to initialize W and b later on anyways as W below won't be initialized by the zeros tensor.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3,4]), name='x')
b = tf.Variable(x + 6, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
#Error: Attempting to use uninitialized value b
```

The example above will give an error but the one below won't and will give the correct answer.

```
W = tf.zeros([3,4], name='x')
b = tf.Variable(x + 6, name='y')

model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(model)
```

If you want to do it the way you're with weights and biases (I'm guessing W and b stand for) I suggest looking here.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#variable-scope-example

Let me know if you still have any questions.